# How to turn iOS camera off

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, away3d

I’m working on an IOS app in which video from the iPad's camera is displayed on a plane in an Away3D environment.

```
private function liveVideoCamera():void {
   liveCamera = getCamera(CameraPosition.FRONT); 
   liveCamera.setMode(1024, 730, 30);

   var cameraTexture:WebcamTexture = new WebcamTexture(570,340,8,true,liveCamera,true);
   var cameraMaterial:TextureMaterial = new TextureMaterial(cameraTexture);

   var planeGeom:PlaneGeometry = new PlaneGeometry(570, 340, 1, 1, false, true);
   cameraScreen = new Mesh(planeGeom, cameraMaterial);
   cameraScreen.y=210;
   cameraScreen.x=wall.x;
   cameraScreen.z=wall.z;
   cameraScreen.rotationY=90;
   scene.addChild(cameraScreen);
  }
```

What I cannot find is a way to turn the camera off. Apple will not allow an app to operate the camera without user permission. The app is a puzzle game with more than one player allowed. I need new players to begin with the camera turned off if a previous player left it turned on.

I have found several suggestions on the web that say to set the video attached to the camera to null. But as you can see there is no video:Video involved in the method. The camera outputs to cameraTexture:WebcamTexture instead.

Comment: Obtain permission from the user to operate the camera.

Comment: why not just put a black texture over it and then when you need the camera again, reapply the camera texture?

Comment: That would work but Apple is pretty stringent. I'd be afraid they would know the camera was still on.

Comment: Turns out it's a simple thing to do inside Away3D.  cameraTexture.stop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `liveCamera` is WebcamTexture from Away3D, it has a public method called `stop` :)

Otherwise you should use `attachCamera(null)` to the video.